# No exclusive rights after removing tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

In MS Access 2007 I imported some CSV files. These imports do create import errors as some of the fields have extensive text that cannot be stored in a memo field. For these errors, MS Access creates new tables with import errors for every single file that it imports. I created a sub that deletes the import error tables and, in general, that works fine. What is not fine is that after the code has run I'm no longer the administrator of the database and I first need to close the database before I can continue with further development on the database.

```
Sub DelteTbls() 

On Error GoTo DelteTbls_Error

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    Set db = CurrentDb() 'Set the database object

    'Clean the import error tables.
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If (tdf.Name Like "*" & "import" & "*") Then
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.Name
        End If
    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

SmoothExit_DelteTbls:
    Set db = Nothing
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

DelteTbls_Error:
    MsgBox "Error" & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DelteTbls"
    Resume SmoothExit_DelteTbls

End Sub
```

The message I get after this code has run is

> Microsoft Access can't save design changes or save to a new database object as another user has the file open. To save your design changes or to save to a new object you must have exclusive access to the file.

This is strange, as I'm the only user of the database and no-one else is logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean *I am no longer the administrator of the database*?

Comment: If you are going to import CSV files into an access database, you will want to leave the table definition as open as possible. The Memo field should be able to hold as much data as you want. What you then do is write some VBA code that processes that memo data for errors. In other words, you handle it yourself instead of letting Access to do it for you.

Comment: Consider using more than one Access database and importing the data from one to the other, or stop using Access and get a free version of SQL Server Express which is much much better.

Comment: @braX Although the Memo field might be able to hold more data, this does not guarantee that the import tools honor the same limits.

Comment: It is bad practice to delete an object from a collection being enumerated.  Instead, collect the names (in another collection) of the TableDef objects separately, then delete them in a separate loop after the first loop is finished.  (As is, the code still has a reference to the TableDef when it is deleted, potentially causing an object reference problem that might be the source of the problem.)

Comment: Instead of using DoCmd methods, execute an SQL command `DROP TABLE [Table Name]` [See reference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177897(v=office.12).aspx)  DoCmd is an Access method that likely creates redundant database connections... a possible source of the problem.

Comment: I agree with CPerkins that you should avoid using `DoCmd`, but I personally prefer `TableDefs.Delete tdf.Name` over a `DROP TABLE` query.

Comment: @Brax: it means that I can't edit my code any longer as I'm not the sole user of the dbase any longer hence I can't modify and save my code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions: With drop statements i get syntax errors. I tried two options inserted after 'then' attempt 1: str = "DROP TABLE" & str & ""
            DoCmd.RunSQL str  || attempt2: db.execute "DROP TABLE" & tdf.Name & ";" both didn't  drop the tables and also placed the dbase again in 'administration' mode

Comment: With the Tabledefs.Delete tdf.name statement I get another error: (Object required) in procedure DelteTbls  with the result that it didn't drop the tables either and also placed the dbase again in a not exclusive state. (not able to modify&save the code changes)

Comment: Resolved: Two steps I took to get it resolved: 1=created a new empty access dbase and imported all tables,forms,queries,modules from the old dbase. 2: I replaced my code between the error handling with this     Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
 
    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
         If InStr(tbl.Name, "ImportErrors") Then
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete (tbl.Name)
        End If
    Next tbl 
Thank you for your suggestions to get it work.